# Android 10 - alternative to launching executable as subproccess stored in app home directory

Tags: android, xamarin, android-10.0

I have an android app (C#, Xamarin) that

1. bundles a python environment with its apk.
2. extracts the python files into an the app files directory.
3. runs python code, by executing the python executable as a sub process.

This worked for years, but now on android 10, I'm getting:

`Write fault on path /[Unknown]` error (which is likely the Xamarin wrapper of the real error).

I assume this is caused by the following android 10 changes:
["Removed execute permission for app home directory"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission)

(Although if I `adb` in and `runas` the app user, executing the python executable works fine.)

My testing showed that:
In general running subproccess still works. (eg /system/bin/echo)
But executing any subprocess, that exists in the apps home/files directory generates the `Write fault on path /[Unknown]` error.

In the android 10 changes file, the suggested alternative approach is to:

> Apps should load only the binary code that's embedded within an app's
>   APK file.

As far as I'm aware one can't get a file path to an embedded apk file.

Is there a way of executing (eg. Runtime.exec()) a (binary/native) file embedded in the apk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to execute a binary/native file embedded inside an APK. However, since android automatically extracts files in the lib/[ABI](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis)/ folder on install, I was able to put my python executable in that folder.

In addition, even though the [docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis) seem to imply that only files of the form `lib<name>.so` are extracted, I found that all files in that folder were extracted.
(***UPDATE: apparently only for DEBUG builds?***)
Sub folders are always ignored and never extracted.

**UPDATE**: while the above is true for lots of android environments , I found that chromebook android environments, only files of the form `lib<name>.so` are installed. Even files of the form `lib<name>.so.<version>` are ignored.

---

The process was like this:

- place binary/native files in the `lib/ABI` folder of the APK.

I used the jar.exe tool to add files to my apk. (for other build environment there is prolly easier ways)

- In application code, find the **install** location of the apk. (not the data dir)

I used:

```java
PackageManager.GetApplicationInfo("my.app.name", PackageInfoFlags.SharedLibraryFiles).NativeLibraryDir
```

- Exec binary/native prog from that folder.

It will be something like this.

```
/data/app/my.app.name-RmBFingPOpsEA-S577DoZg==/lib/x86_64
```

---

An added benefit of this approach is that the app doesn't have to extract the native files itself, rather that is done automatically on install. This improves app startup time.

Comment: Hi Tom, I added an executable file to src/main/resource/ABI and in debug builds it is copied to the NativeLibraryDir, however after assembleRelease it is not, any idea why that would be? thanks

Comment: @MandelDuck - sorry no, I build with VS, I guess you are using Android Studio? I find when looking at things like this, extracting and examining the output APK's, to make sure their contents are as I expect them is helpful.

Comment: thanks for the reply, are you able to say if you get the same issue? or does it build fine on release? if it doesnt it makes me think its something with react native breaking things, I noticed that some react native .so files were copied and managed to get my executable file included if I renamed it lib*.so and hid it in the folder where react kept its .so files

Comment: @MandelDuck - works fine for me, with my build system, release or debug) (Xamarin). Worse case you can also add files to the apk afterwards using jar.exe. (apk's are just zip/jar files). Will have to resign with Apksigner if you modify after the signing. I do it before.  see $(JavaToolPath)\jar.exe. My csproj calls look like this:     <Exec Command="&quot;$(JavaToolPath)\jar.exe&quot; -uMf &quot;$(MonoAndroidIntermediate)android\bin\$(_AndroidPackage).apk&quot; -C &quot;$(ProjectDir)\armeabi-v7a&quot; lib\armeabi-v7a" Condition="$(ARCH) == 'armeabi-v7a'" />

Comment: thanks, yes that makes sense, I tried to add them afterward but had an issue with the signing, never done it manually but thanks for the instructions

Comment: @Tom, that does not appear to work when adding manually and resigning. I added files to the lib/[arch] folder and they are not included unless in the lib[name].so format. Furthermore, even when an executable is named that way, it cannot be executed as a process.

Comment: @g01d - yes I found it needed to be named .so on some systems (that is included in the answer). I can successfully execute a process, named that way. Are you sure the exec isn't failing for other reasons? (like missing shared lib deps? or wrong arch?)

Comment: @g01d - for example I have a process named : "libexepython2.7.so" (which is just the python exe - compiled for the appropriate arch). I run this as a subprocess from an android app, after ensuring all its shared lib deps are met.

Comment: @Tom, yep, I've tried everything, and it doesn't run from Java. The process returns exit code 1 and does not execute. No dependencies. This might well be device dependent, but I'm using a Google Pixel. Also, it is a bit absurd that it has to be named libX.so to run... clearly they aren't intending this to work.

Comment: @g01d - (I've tested on pixel emulator for android 10 +11, plus I have pixel users in the wild.) have you tried executing something that's already on the system - eg. /system/bin/cat ? if that works, try copying that to libcat.so and placing in your folder. Failing that you could always dlopen instead of launching a subprocess. (that is what I do on iOS)

Comment: *`all files in that folder were extracted`* – this is only true for debug version; for **release**, all Android systems enforce the **lib….so** filter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a just a **short term workaround** (rather than a proper answer):

change android `targetSdkVersion` from `29` to `28`

This means, that things should work even on android 10 devices, however it has the following limitations:

1. You can never upgrade the target sdk version.
2. At some point in future the google play store will not allow app uploads that target older sdk versions, means you can't post upgrades to your app.