# ProcessBuilder in my Android app: Cannot run .so file stored in jniLibs

Tags: java, android, exception, adb, processbuilder

Came across this project on github: https://github.com/tytydraco/LADB

Even though I don't read Kotlin, as far as I can tell, the developer is not importing methods from the libadb.so into his own code; he is simply treating the libadb.so as an executable. So, he just executes the file along with the actual command by running a background process, the end result would be something like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder(adbPath+command)).directory(this.getFilesDir()).start();
```

**adbPath** is the absolutePath of where the libadb.so is located. Pre-compilation the file is stored in the jniLibs folder.
**command** could be for instance `pair localhost:2334` or `shell`.

The thing is I get this exception when starting the process:

```
2022-08-28 15:44:43.638 10591-13931/com.test.myapplication I/System.out: Cannot run program "/data/app/~~lCjz17EMQQ7-XVoYrYa1Jw==/com.test.myapplication-9MADOh8OORG__Li17fkr6Q==/lib/arm64/libadb.so" (in directory "/data/user/0/com.test.myapplication/files"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Why there is no such file or directory? And what would I need to do to fix this?

Comment: That may be caused by the restriction Google introduced some time ago: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission

Comment: @Robert then how is the developer able to execute it?

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800440/android-cant-execute-process-for-android-api-29-android-10-from-lib-arch

Comment: @Robert thank you for pointing that out! However, I failed to see how to solve the issue.