# How to access /data/data/my.package.app/files directory on Android 9+?

Tags: android-studio, filesystems

I have a script *(my_script)* in my application that I copy to the directory with the application and then call it through the terminal, for example,

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec('/data/user/0/my.package.app/files/my_script --version');
```

This works on a stb with Android 7, but it does not work on stb with Android 9 and on a smartphone with Android 11. If you call this command on a smartphone with Android 11, then there will be an error **'inaccessible or not found'**, and on Sberbox just **'not found'**

Tell me please, what's the matter? Is there a better way to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Rename file to `lib<name>.so`, then put in all folders in **jniLibs**

You can get the file path like this: `getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir + '/lib<name>.so'`

Example: `/data/app/~~GoeS1231GPseyGfbY212fg==/you.package.app-21xvsvRGysqVb2_OXnI-DD==/lib/arm64/lib<name>.so`

Add in manifest `android:extractNativeLibs="true"`

Also add `implementation fileTree(include: ['.so'], dir: 'libs')` to **dependencies** in **build.gradle**

This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62394766/10946427